# Is there any danger to directly evaluate user-supplied regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, security, browser

I want to let users supply their own regular expressions for searching through data supplied by me. I'm concerned solely with the browser environment, be it a webpage or a Browser Extension (my thinking here is that it doesn't matter which it is).

From what I've read, the primary concern with user-supplied regexes is that it is very easy to cause a DoS. In my case the offending user would only DoS herself (which isn't too much of a concern for me, and off course I'll supply all necessary warnings).

What I want to avoid or prevent is the usual user ignorance attack - users getting "advice" from others as what to enter. Think of the very common "if you enter your password, Facebook will display black dost instead" or the usual warning when one opens the browser development console.

My biggest concern is code injection in the context of Browser Extension, in which case other tabs can be accessed or manipulated (given the extension has the rights - let's assume the worst case scenario here). Is there any way this is possible in Javascript?

*Update to clarify:*

The target audience are power users who are comfortable with regular expressions, but my concern are people not well versed in development, who can be targeted by simple "open this page/install this add-on".

The entered expressions will be persisted in Local Storage or the add-on persistence mechanism. Always client side. One vector here could be if the browser is shared by multiple users. Think of a naughty grandson changing noscript settings for his grampa.

The expressions will not be passed over in URL.

*Use case*

The website supplies a list of URLs together with some data of interest to the user. I want the user to be able to filter the list (technically a map where the URL is the key) not only by substring, but with a regular expression as well. E. g. `http(s?):` for including http and https in the search.

Comment: Code injection through an extension wouldn't rely on your regex feature. It's trivial to inject a DoS producing code on any page, the contents or operation of the page are irrelevant. So I don't think that should be your primary concern. What are you actually doing with the regex? Is it *in any way* persisted? Not limited to a database - it could even in the URL? If so, you have a potential injection vector. And what is this search for? Because most of the users won't benefit from regex. The ones who do would be advanced users and they should be fine with entering problematic ones.

Comment: @vlaz Thank you for your questions, I'll edit the answer into the original post since I think they are important to the question.